# Change ALL links, hrefs,urls with vanilla Javascript & regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace the url values on the entire page using some vanilla Javascript. I cannot use ANY library/framework. Here's what I have so far which has been placed at the top of each page between the  tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function change_url() {
    var str = '';
    str = str.replace(/blog\.domain\.info/g, 'blogtest\.domain\.info');
}
change_url();
</script>
```

However, this isn't working when the page loads.

Basically, I need resource links to go from http://blog.domain.info to http://blogtest.domain.info. Simple task, I know! But the code above isn't working so far.

Suggestions on what to change?

Comment: "vanilla Javascript" - you are making your life harder than necessary. jQuery etc. ftw!

Comment: Do you mean just `<a>` anchors, or are you including all images, and other entities such as stylesheets, javascript files, etc?

Comment: Can't use any type of framework/library...HAS to be vanilla.

Comment: @Orbling Everything! a href, link, src....EVERYTHING. Is it possible?

Comment: I'll answer as an answer, novel approach I know, started in a comment and then I gibbered on too long.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After reading your comment, you need something like

```
function replace_url(elem, attr) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName(elem);
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
        elems[i][attr] = elems[i][attr].replace('blog.domain.info', 'blogtest.domain.info');
}

window.onload = function() {
    replace_url('a', 'href');
    replace_url('img', 'src');
    // etc
}
```

Comment: No problem. :) <extra text to get past the min comment length>

Answer (score 3):

If you're targeting links, you can do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
        len = els.length;

    while( len-- ) {
        els[len].hostname = els[len].hostname.replace('blog.domain.info','blogtest.domain.info');
    }
</script>
```

Place this script just inside the closing `</body>` tag.

For additional tags, specify the tag name and property you're updating.

Comment: This is pretty awesome as well! Didn't see this one in time but will try it out as well. Thank you for your help and information.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is very difficult, as how do you get items in the header to be altered before they are encountered?  If you can force your JS to run before load, perhaps, but I doubt it.  You could go along post-load, find the entries, rewrite them and load them asynchronously, but code may well miss initialisation events that way.  It'll get complicated.

Elements can be addressed using the `getElementsByTagName()` approach that other answers mention.  This is fine for `src/href` changes, but will not take care of CSS imagery, `background-image` in particular, which can occur on a lot of elements.  Then there is the issue of such things attached to classes, which will require scouring of class entries, which is a pain.  I doubt altering meta information like RSS feeds, favicons, etc, will take effect post load.

It would be better to handle it server-side really.

Comment: This was a great explanation and I totally agree. Wish i could but this is for a platform that's already got functions and stuff floating around. Moving the JS to server-side would be ideal but would require major changes throughout. But I totally agree with your assessment!

Comment: Oh I didn't mean move the JS server-side, move the URL changes, it's all in the HTML/CSS, so you just need to parse it and make the alterations.  In ASP.Net you can just catch the PreRender event, if it's PHP, you could use output buffering and probably regex that sort of change.

Comment: Output buffering is what I would use ordinarily. However, not an option...yet!

Answer (score 1):

I’m way too late for the party but hope this helps someone else.

Your code is perfect, it just needs the text to work on and a way to feed it back so this is what I would do, mind you I’m not an expert just a fiddler.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//added “str” as a function input/parameter
function change_url(str) {
    /* removed this
    var str = ''; */
    /* changed this
    str = 
    to this */
    return str.replace(/blog\.domain\.info/g, 'blogtest\.domain\.info');
}
//and called it like this
document.onload = function(){
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].outerHTML = change_url(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].outerHTML);
}
</script>
```

And if you wanted to change all references on the entire document than you would just call it like this.

```
document.onload = function(){
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].outerHTML = change_url(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].outerHTML);
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].outerHTML = change_url(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].outerHTML);
}
```

This will change all reference to blog.domain.info in src, href, img, and any instance found in !!TEXT!!.
So be careful using it, because all forementioned references will be changed.  ;o)

Comment: All good. Never too late. Thank you for the code. Much appreciated!